# Graphdb restore from backup in curl

Tags: graphdb

I'm writing a script to automatically setup a repository starting from a clean GraphDB running in a Docker container.
I have a config.ttl file containing repository configuration, the namespace and a dump in a file init.nq 
I have successfully created the repository using the config.ttf and updated namespace but I cannot understand how to load the init.nq file.

This operation is extremely simple from web interface: Import -> RFD -> Upload, but I'm not able to understand how to perform it using Curl. I suppose that the correct API should be

```
post /repositories/{repositoryID}/statements
```

but the dump is to huge to pass it as simple text (~44MB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/n-quads" -T init.nq  'http://localhost:7200/repositories/test/statements'